# Custom array sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

At first - yes, I've tried to find my problem here, but can't make it.

I have a problem with array sorting. I want to use custom array sorting to sort some data taken from DB.

For example, I have array

```
values: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 14830, 78426, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6024, 1144, 4438, 19282 ]
```

And I need to get last 4 (sometimes 3 or 2, so it would be custom) results on the first place in the same order as they are now. And the result should be like:

```
values: [ 6024, 1144, 4438, 19282, 14830, 78426, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
```

How can I do that?

I make this array with

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($re))
{
$dates = $row['mon'];

 while ($current_month != $dates) {
  $current_month = $current_month + 1;
  if($current_month == 13)
  $current_month = 1;
  $data[] = 0;
 }
 $data[] = intval($row['type']);
 $current_month = $dates+1;
}
```

I take months number as $current_month and using it puts my data in right places. When month have no results it adds 0 in that place. 
The results should be just 6 and when there's no passing through the years it makes array right, but sometimes it goes wrong like this, so I want to make proper array using custom sorting like I mantioned at first.

So I want to sort this array and with array_slice cut it to 6.

Thanks for help.

Comment: J0HN understand what I want and make it really good and quick.
I have to make it custom and it would work well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$desired_length = 4;
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
$length = count($arr);
$array = array_slice($arr, $length-$desired_length, $desired_length) + array_slice($arr,0,$length-$desired_length);
```

Comment: It worked very well. That's what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$svalues = array_slice($values, 4);
rsort(&$svalues);
$array = array_merge(array_slice($values, count($values) - 4, 4), $svalues);
```

Comment: Sorry, but: *Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in*

Comment: Then remove the `&` out of the second line.

Comment: Gereby needs last four elements in front, in the same order as they were. Your code left first four elements as they were (i.e. [0,0,0,0,....], and than append reversed array.

Answer (score 0):

here is an exmaple of custom sort.. I am not sure if I understood your question correctly to help you there.. but this should give u an idea..

```
var myMultiArray = [    {"Name": "Steve", "Age":41},
{"Name": "Joe", "Age":55},
{"Name": "Robert", "Age":34},
{"Name": "Alex", "Age":35}];

function customMultiSort(a, b) {
return (a['Age'] - b['Age']);
}

myMultiArray.sort(customMultiSort);
document.write(myMultiArray.toSource());
```